# Apache Spark job runs locally but throwing null pointer on Google Cloud Cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have an application for Apache Spark that I have been until now running/testing on local machine using command:

```
spark --class "main.SomeMainClass" --master local[4] jarfile.jar
```

And everything runs alright however when I submit this very same job to Google Cloud Dataproc Engine it throws `NullPointerException` as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at geneticClasses.FitnessCalculator.calculateFitness(FitnessCalculator.java:30)
at geneticClasses.StringIndividualMapReduce.calculateFitness(StringIndividualMapReduce.java:91)
at mapreduce.Mapper.lambda$mapCalculateFitness$3d84c37$1(Mapper.java:30)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1018)
at 
.
.
.
```

This error is thrown from worker node as it's occuring during `map` phase. What's the difference between local mode and actual cluster except that local mode just simulates worker nodes as separate threads? `FitnessCalculator` sits on driver node and all methods are static. Do I need to make it `Serializable` so it can be shipped to the worker node together with other code?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information.  Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: I wish I could but it's my BSc final year project and I can't put any of my code online due to either plagiarism or collusion. I was afraid that you might not have enough information to know what the problem is

Comment: You say that `FitnessCalculator` only has static methods and that it works in `local` mode.  My guess is that you have some static object (initialized to `null`) that you set in the driver and then attempt to use within a Spark task at `FitnessCalculator.java:30`.  That won't work.

Comment: Ok I guess it makes sense when I think about it now that you can't access static methods and fields sitting on the driver node from worker. I changed my code so I serialize FitnessCalculator and send it to the worker node together with other code and it solved the problem described above. Thanks

Comment: Excellent.  I'll make it an answer for the next person that has this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that `FitnessCalculator` only has static methods and that it works in local mode. My guess is that you have some static object (initialized to `null`) that you set in the driver and then attempt to use within a Spark task at `FitnessCalculator.java:30`. That won't work unfortunately.

Changes to static fields aren't distributed to Spark workers.  The reason it works in `local` mode is that the workers are running within the same JVM (Java Virtual Machine) as the driver, so they coincidentally have access to the new value.